# FTPWebRequest: Transfer from one FTP to another FTP, Destination file corrupt

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Here's my agonizing problem. I'm transferring from one FTP (a Dev site) to another FTP (a Test site). Spare me the thoughts of changing this process. It's out of my hands. In any case, here's my method:

```
Public Function TransferFile(originalFile As String, destinationFile As String) As String
        Try
            'FileStream for holding the file
            Dim uploadRequest As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(destinationFile)
            uploadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            uploadRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pw)
            uploadRequest.UseBinary = True
            uploadRequest.UsePassive = False

            'connect to the server
            Dim fileRequest As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(originalFile)
            fileRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
            fileRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pw)
            fileRequest.UseBinary = True
            fileRequest.UsePassive = False

            'get the servers response
            Dim response As WebResponse = fileRequest.GetResponse()

            'retrieve the response stream
            Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            CopyStream(stream, uploadRequest.GetRequestStream)

            stream.Close()
            response.Close()

            Return "File transfered"
        Catch ex As System.Security.SecurityException
            Return ex.Message
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub CopyStream(input As Stream, output As Stream)
      Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(32767) {}
       While True
        Dim read As Integer = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        If read <= 0 Then
            Return
        End If
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read)
       End While
    End Sub
```

This works perfectly for ASPX files and their .vb code behinds. When we try to transfer .DLL files, they show up on the server as 0 bytes, and sometimes actually transfer. The problem is that, despite being the same size as the original, they act as if they are corrupt. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I just did a test using your code and it worked just fine for me. I diff'd the two DLLs and they were identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing out the output stream and getting a response from the uploadRequest worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - use BYREF in your sub definition

Public Shared Sub CopyStream(BYREF input As Stream, BYREF output As Stream)

Comment: That would allow him to point `input` and `output` to new variables which his method isn't doing.